# Issues using self as a method argument in python

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I apologize for the basic question but I am having some issues with either syntax or the overall concept I think. The problem I am having is that when I call the method in the class below the interpreter wants me to input a value for the self argument which I don't think is supposed to happen. What I am trying to do is create an object to hold several tkinter widgets at once so that I can dynamically add or subtract them in groups rather than one at a time. Any help here is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
class User(object):

    #Input a UI row number and this will generate a corresponding row of widgets
    def generateLine(self, rowNumber):
        self.NameVar = StringVar()
        self.ReasonVar = StringVar()
        #ExcusedVar

        self.Name_Cbox = ec.AutocompleteCombobox(content, textvariable = self.NameVar)
        self.Name_Cbox.grid(row = rowNumber, column = 0)

        self.Reason_Cbox = ec.AutocompleteCombobox(content, textvariable = self.ReasonVar)
        self.Reason_Cbox.grid(row = rowNumber, column = 1)
```

Comment: When you have a python problem that produces a traceback, always include that in your question. It helps us much, much more than having to guess what kind of error you had.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have an *instance* of your `User` class to call the method on:

```
user = User()
user.generateLine(0)
```

`self` is only provided when the method has been bound to an instance.

If you call the method directly on the class, you'll get an exception:

```
>>> class User(object):
...     def generateLine(self, row):
...         print row
... 
>>> User.generateLine(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method generateLine() must be called with User instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
>>> User().generateLine(0)
0
```

Comment: Nice example +1... I would just add for the OP, that it might be worth considering in the design (although given such a short example, it's difficult to tell) to have `__getitem__ = generateLine` in the class def.

Comment: @JonClements: The OP's method doesn't return anything. I think using the method as it stands as a `__getitem__` is a bad idea.

Comment: Okay, I concede the point about `__getitem__` - I somehow saw a `return` statement that wasn't there :) But will try to redeem myself by saying, `generateLine` should return the generated line, and `__getitem__` should be used for retrieving generated lines? ;)

Comment: @JonClements: Nope; the method adds elements to a UI, that's a different goal altogether. :-)